# WsaRecv/GetQueuedCompletionStatus reads the data late

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, winsock2, iocp

we are using IOCP with winsock 2 in vc++ and overlapped WsaRecv to issue async read request on socket. worker threads are waiting on GetQueuedCompletionStatus to receive the data. we have applied wireshark and observed that some times not everytime data arrives at say 00:00:01 time but GetQueuedCompletionStatus receives it after 8-10 seconds instead of immediately or event after latency in milliseconds. the threads are blocked in waiting status upon GetQueuedCompletionStatus so i dont suspect a foul in our code. have any one observed or experienced that. any suggested solution as we cannot afford delay in our mission critical application. we have applied this registry patch too but no affect. [Improve recv latency by ignoring push flag](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcp-push-flag.html)

this is written in the worker thread.

```
BOOL bReturn = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
        m_hCompletionPort,
        &dwBytesTransfered,
        (PULONG_PTR)&lpContext,
        &pOverlapped,
        INFINITE);
```

and this is the async WsaRecv already issued over the socket.

```
if(WSARecv(m_socket,m_receiveBuffer->GetIOBuffer(),1,&dwBytes,&dwFlags,&(this->m_receiveOV.ol),NULL)==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        if(error!=ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            this->Close(iThreadNo);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any code we might be able to actually _look_ at ([MCVE])?  Thanks

Comment: Are *all* the threads blocked in GQCS when this happens? Or only some of them? It's quite likely that you've just hit the specified concurrency limit due to blocking on I/O in the IOCP threads.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz all the threads are blocked on io and to tell you the fact there is only once socket that is connected.

Comment: @MubashirKhan When you say "blocked on io", do you mean they're blocked on GQCS? Or do you mean they're blocked on other I/O operations?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i mean blocked on GQCS.

Comment: If you're quite sure that every thread that ever blocked on GQCS is currently blocked on GCQS, the the issue isn't what I was thinking it was. I would, however, suggest that you make absolutely sure this is the case, because the issue I'm thinking of is almost always the explanation for the behavior you're seeing.